# Smarter indentation in zim

Tags: autohotkey

I use [zim](http://zim-wiki.org/index.html) as my personal wiki. I would like to make the indentation work better. So I tried to create this ahk-script.

```
^!left::
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
IfWinExist, zim
    WinActivate, zim
    send, {Home}
    send, {shift} & {Tab}
return
```

But it does not work. I suspect it's the {shift} & {Tab} that's incorrectly written. How do I make two button at the same time?

Comment: "would like to make the indentation work better": What *exactly* do you want to do? In what way do you want indentation to "work better"?

Comment: It's worth studying the reference docs for AutoHotKey as they are very good.

Here is a page regarding Modifiers that should assist you: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm

Comment: Bob, as you see in the code, what I wish to do is to hit ^!left and make the computer type Home and then shift+tab.